# FILE_URI returns base64 string in Ionic 2

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm creating a camera app with ionic 2. I installed cordova-plugin-camera and accessed it via ionic native API. Cordova states that if I specify destinationType as Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI, then the callback returns the uri of the captured image. However when I test it on browser I always get a base64 string instead of the URI of the image. Is there anything I'm missing?

```
  takePicture() {
      Camera.getPicture({
          destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
          saveToPhotoAlbum: true,
          allowEdit: false
          //targetWidth: 1000,
          //targetHeight: 1000
      }).then((imageURI) => {
          console.log(imageURI);
      }, (err) => {
          console.log(err);
      });
  }
```

Comment: How are you using the camera plugin in browser? Those cordova plugins only work on the device themselves, not browser.

Comment: I can invoke the webcam in the browser. Because it's easier to test with the browser